# How to add aar file to react-native project?

Tags: android, react-native

I am building a react-native project but not able to add an `aar` file as a dependency.

I have followed following steps

1. Created libs folder and placed aar file in that.
2. Written this in top level Gradle

   ```
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
   ```
3. added following line to dependencies

   ```
   compile project(name: "xyz", ext: 'aar')
   ```

And I am facing this error while building

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-abc'.
> Required keys [path] are missing from map {name=xyz, ext=aar}.
```

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

-> In Step 2, just make sure that while adding

```
    flatDir{ 
       dirs 'libs' 
    }
```

in repositories , repository belongs to allprojects instead of buildscript.

-> In step 3 try this :

```
    compile(name: "xyz",ext: 'aar')
```